# Crystal Crosstab need help adding columns to highlight average and difference

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I have a crosstab which shows a count of a callid for this month and previous month by customer id this is showing a top 10 group. My problem is I need to have a column that shows the difference between this month and previous month and then I need a column for the 12 month average

i.e. My crosstab currently looks like this

```
                             Sept        Aug
Customer1                     80         20
Customer2                     56         58
Customer3                     60         88
Customer4                     71         54
Customer5                     98         45
```

I need it to look like this

```
                            Sept        Aug       Difference     12mthAvg
Customer1                     80         20        60              65
Customer2                     56         58        -2              73
Customer3                     60         88       -28              52
Customer4                     71         54        17              48
Customer5                     98         45        53              56
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Annette

Comment: Which version of Crystal Reports are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monthly average is easy.  Right click the first row in the 'Total' column (by default, this is the left-most column), select 'Edit Summary...', and choose 'Average' from the 'Calculate this summary' combo-box.  This assumes that the cross-tab always includes 12 months of data, which can be easily done by setting an appropriate record-selection formula.

I'll do some research on the monthly deltas and post my results.

** edit **

If you have Crystal Reports 2008, you can add a calculated column.  You will need to have 11 of these.

Here are the steps:

1. Select the second column's header and choose Calculated Member | Insert Column.
2. Right click the first cell in the new column and select Calculated Member | Edit Calculation Formula
3. Enter the following in the formula's text:

   //find the difference in values of the current row in the two columns to the left of the 
     //current (calculated) column
     GridValueAt(CurrentRowIndex,CurrentColumnIndex-1,CurrentSummaryIndex) +
     GridValueAt(CurrentrowIndex,CurrentColumnIndex-2,CurrentSummaryIndex)
4. Change the column header's text by right clicking the header and choosing Calculated Member | Edit Header Formula'.
5. Repeat steps 1-4 for each calculated column.  In step 3, change the offset from -2 to -3 to account for the presence of the calculated column.

Comment: Click the check mark at the left side of my answer.  It will turn green to indicate that it is the accepted answer.  If you feel that an answer (or a question for that matter) is a good one, click the arrow above the number.